# Размещение веб-сервиса на хостинге

Tags: asp.net, хостинг

Создал веб-сервис `.asmx` для андроид-приложения, отладил на локальном компьютере.

Каким образом перенести его на хостинг, чтобы сервер был доступен постоянно?

Подскажите, есть ли такая возможность, и какими хостингами для веб-сервисов вы пользовались (преимущественно бесплатными).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правой кнопкой по проекту в студии / Publish. Там выбираете способ публикации - ftp/web deploy/file system. Первые два зальют напрямую на сервер. File System просто сложит результат в указанную папку, которую потом надо будет вручную скопировать на сервер.

Публикация сводится к компиляции проекта и копировании из него всех файлов, кроме самих исходников. В вашем случае студия скорее всего сама правильно определит, что надо копировать, а что - нет. Т.е. просто скопирует все, кроме исходников.

Из бесплатных/дешевых хостингов - [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/) (если нагрузка небольшая). Публикация на Azure встроена в студию, в этот самый диалог Publish. А с некоторых пор - еще и в диалог создания проекта.